# TinyDuino RadioHead compile error with TinyZero

Tags: arduino-zero

I have a stack of TinyDuino boards including

[TinyZero](https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyzero-processor) and [433MHZ Long Range Radio TinyShield](https://tinycircuits.com/products/433mhz-long-range-radio-tinyshield).

I previously has this [processor](https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyduino-processor-board) and had no problem compiling the sketch 
and uploading it.

With the [TinyZero](https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyzero-processor) now I get the following error.

```
RadioHead.h:463:29: error: RHutil/atomic.h: No such file or directory
   #include <RHutil/atomic.h>
```

Obviously there is a file missing, when I tried to copy the file from the web
I got another error saying:

```
    sketch/RHHardwareSPI.cpp: In member function 'virtual void RHHardwareSPI::begin()':
RHHardwareSPI.cpp:99:58: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'BitOrder' [-fpermissive]
     _settings = SPISettings(frequency32, bOrder, dataMode);
                                                          ^
In file included from sketch/RHGenericSPI.h:13:0,
                 from sketch/RHHardwareSPI.h:10,
                 from sketch/RHHardwareSPI.cpp:7:
/home/ktsirakos/.arduino15/packages/TinyCircuits/hardware/samd/1.0.8/libraries/SPI/SPI.h:50:3: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'SPISettings::SPISettings(uint32_t, BitOrder, uint8_t)' [-fpermissive]
   SPISettings(uint32_t clock, BitOrder bitOrder, uint8_t dataMode) {
   ^
```

What the board does is to get Accelerometer values and send it to a receiver with the same RadioHead board.

I think it is because of the ARM of the TinyZero processor because the RadioHead.h header file includes these lines of code.

```
    // This is an attempt to make a portable atomic block
#if (RH_PLATFORM == RH_PLATFORM_ARDUINO)
#if defined(__arm__)
  #include "atomic.h"
 #else
  #include <util/atomic.h>
 #endif
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_START     ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_END }
#elif (RH_PLATFORM == RH_PLATFORM_UNO32)
 #include <peripheral/int.h>
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_START unsigned int __status = INTDisableInterrupts(); {
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_END } INTRestoreInterrupts(__status);
#else 
 // TO BE DONE:
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_START
 #define ATOMIC_BLOCK_END
#endif
```

Any suggestion if it is possible to run these 2 together? ([TinyZero](https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyzero-processor) and [RadioHead](https://tinycircuits.com/products/433mhz-long-range-radio-tinyshield))?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: When using the newest RadioHead and a new official arduino Zero with a new bootloader from arduino.cc, it should work according to the RadioHead page: https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/ How old is the core software for the TinyZero?

Comment: Helly @Jot , the software has been build to run on this processor: https://tinycircuits.com/products/tinyduino-processor-board?variant=14479557959

Comment: Konstantinos Tsirakos, that is with the atmega328p microcontroller, the same as in the arduino uno, nano, pro mini and so on. That is very compatible. The arduino zero and clones with samd21 processors are not so compatible. There are even a few different official arduino boards with the samd21 (arduino M0, arduino zero, arduino mkr). I think they build a new core environment for the TinyZero which is somehow going in its own direction or is too old.

Comment: The problem was with the drivers, I updated them from the site you send to me and everything worked ok with that. :)

Comment: That's very nice. I try to keep up with the newest software/firmware/bootloaders. For me, a arduino clone is no problem, as long as I can use the arduino software. I stay away from other "compatible" boards that have their own core.